# Trying to fetch Data from Database. Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to fetch the data from a database to a table. I have created a **service** like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Post } from "./post.model";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class PostsService {
  private posts: Post[] = [];
  private postsUpdated = new Subject<Post[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; posts: any }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/posts"
      )
      .pipe(map((postData) => {
        return postData.posts.map(post => {
          return {
            title: post.title,
            content: post.content,
            id: post._id
          };
        });
      }))
      .subscribe(transformedPosts => {
        this.posts = transformedPosts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }

  getPostUpdateListener() {
    return this.postsUpdated.asObservable();
  }

  addPost(title: string, content: string) {
    const post: Post = { id: null, title: title, content: content };
    this.http
      .post<{ message: string, postId: string }>("http://localhost:3000/api/posts", post)
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        const id = responseData.postId;
        post.id = id;
        this.posts.push(post);
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }

  deletePost(postId: string) {
    this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/api/posts/" + postId)
      .subscribe(() => {
        const updatedPosts = this.posts.filter(post => post.id !== postId);
        this.posts = updatedPosts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }
}
```

When i run the code I get two different errors:

If i use **mozilla** I get:

> ERROR TypeError: "_this.posts is undefined"

If i use **chrome** I get:

> core.js:1542 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of
>   undefined
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (posts.service.ts:39)

Anybody has any idea why is this happening? Thank you

Comment: Which method gives you such errors? Your code shows multiple methods.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `this.posts` is not null in `this.updatedPosts.next([...this.posts])` calls. You can substitute with `this.updatedPosts.next(this.posts)`, so in the case the posts are null you don’t get any runtime errors